# trouble calling a method in the same class java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I've been asked to do the following problem:
Implement a method that accepts an array of integers as input and returns the sum of all of the elements in the array as output.

this is what i have(the entire program):

```
import java.util.*;
public class sumArray{

   public static void main(String[] args){
       int sum1;
       int sum2;
       Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);

       int array[]=new int[5]; // Intilized array of size 5

       for (int i=0;i<5;i++) // used for loop for user input 
       {
           System.out.println("Please enter integer: ");
           array[i]=num.nextInt(); // Assigned users value to array
       }
       System.out.print("The integers are: ");
       for (int i=0;i<5;i++) // for loop to display values 
       {
           System.out.print(array[i]+",");
       }

   }

   public static int sum(int array[]) {
       int sum1 = 0;
       for (int i=0; i < array.length; i++) 
          sum1 = sum1 + array[i];
       return sum1;
   }
}
```

every time I try to call the method "sum" in the main method it gives me an error. I have tried every possible way I've seen on the internet to call the method. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to call it or if it is an issue because I have an array passed to the method. 
Someone please help! and if you see that i've done something incorrectly, please let me know! thanks

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error and fix your code indentation. Where do you make a call to `sum(...)` in your `main` method?

Comment: Please... Indent! My head is spinning!

Comment: `System.out.print(sum(array))` most likely

Comment: Where did you call `sum(...)` in the code?

Comment: `public static int sum(int array[])` this is not the recommended way of declaring an int[] array, see the [documentation page](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays/404/creating-and-initializing-arrays)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class sumArray{

   public static void main(String[] args){
       int sum1;
       int sum2;
       Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);

       int array[]=new int[5]; // Intilized array of size 5

       for (int i=0;i<5;i++) // used for loop for user input 
       {
           System.out.println("Please enter integer: ");
           array[i]=num.nextInt(); // Assigned users value to array
       }
       System.out.print("The integers are: ");
       for (int i=0;i<5;i++) // for loop to display values 
       {
           System.out.print(array[i]+",");
       }
       // this works
       System.out.println("sum is " + sum(array));
   }

   public static int sum(int array[]) {
       int sum1 = 0;
       for (int i=0; i < array.length; i++) 
          sum1 = sum1 + array[i];
       return sum1;
   }
}
```